How to find out the delay applied to audio tracks in an MKV file?
When using mkvmerge to create MKV files, it is possible to specify the --sync parameter to apply a delay to audio tracks.
Is there any way to find out applied delays (if any) in an existing MKV file?
(mkvinfo does not seem to show them).

mkvinfo -v outputs detailed info about which media frame from which track sits at which time position. So, the task boils down to finding the first mention of a frame from a particular track.
For track 2 for example, the delay can be found this way:
mkvinfo -v file.mkv | head -n1000 | grep "Simple block: key, track number 2," | head -n1 | grep -o '[0-9:.]\+' | tail -n1

The longer the expected delay is, the more first lines of mkvinfo output need to be analysed.
